# how to create uiview with transparent background?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I saw this image in patterns.com. I try to create a modal with transparent background but it makes other contents inside uiviewcontroller to become transparent. any ideas?

As below image

[image]

Comment: Of course, you can do something like that

Answer (score 2):

Blur Effect : Swift 3

```
    //add blur effect
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

and this to delete it :

```
    blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
```